# case insensitive comparison in hive

Tags: hive, cloudera, cdp, cloudera-cdp

I have a requirement where I need to do case-insensitive joins across the system and I don't wish to apply upper/lower functions.
I tried setting TBLPROPERTIES('serialization.encoding'='utf8mb4_unicode_ci') at Table level but still the comparison is happening considering case sensitivity.  PSB -

drop table test.caseI;
create table test.caseI
(name string, id int)
TBLPROPERTIES('serialization.encoding'='utf8mb4_unicode_ci');
insert into test.caseI values ('hj',1);

drop table test.caseI_2;
create table test.caseI_2
(name string, id int)
TBLPROPERTIES('serialization.encoding'='utf8mb4_unicode_ci');
insert into test.caseI_2 values ('HJ',1);

select * from test.caseI i
inner join test.caseI_2 i2 on i.name=i2.name;
--No Result

Tried with encoding 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI' but got same result as above.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: i am trying to understand why you need this - can you not use this `select * from test.caseI i inner join test.caseI_2 i2 on lower(i.name)=lower(i2.name);`

Comment: That can be done but the thing is applying functions in join or where clause is a big performance hit and I need to do this in almost 250 scripts running in the batch, which will make the batch perform very slow. That's why I was looking for something at the Database level.

Comment: hmm, i am doubtful if its possible in hive.

Comment: Yes, that's not. I checked that with Cloudera Team as well and they responded that as of now it isn't possible in Hive.